# Validate email address in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my issue: I'm trying to validate an email in the textbox with asp:RegularExpressionValidator, See the below:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="AlertMissedEmail"  Width="300" runat="server" Label="" MaxLength="500" TextMode="MultiLine"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="revEmail" ControlToValidate="AlertMissedEmail"
                                Display="None" ValidationExpression="^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},?)+$"
                                ValidationGroup="validationTourProperties" EnableClientScript="false" 
                                ErrorMessage="- Please enter a valid email address:(ex.) <b>john@gmail.com</b>" />
```

It works just fine if its one email but I want to let the user add multiple emails that can only be separated with semicolon

I want first to check it up in JS so if the user inserted space or something else instead of semicolon the user will get an alert with the correct format how it should be inserted so he can fix the emails.

Please help me fix my JS Code:

```
function formCheck(sender,args)
{
        //Getting the Email field value & text.
        var l_Email = $find("<%=AlertMissedEmail.ClientID %>").get_value();
        var l_EmailText = $find("<%=AlertMissedEmail.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue();
        //Setting up the Reg expression for email.
        var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;

        // 3). Check for reg expression of the email field.
        if (l_EmailText == "") { // text is empty email is not must.
             retValEmail = true;
        }

         if (l_EmailText != "") { // email is not empty check for reg 
            if (reg.test(l_Email)) {
                retValEmail = true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Please enter a valid email address");
                retValEmail = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified you function a bit. This is not tested.
Hope it helps...

```
function formCheck(sender,args)
    {
            //Getting the Email field value & text.
            var l_Email = $find("<%=AlertMissedEmail.ClientID %>").get_value();
            var l_EmailText = $find("<%=AlertMissedEmail.ClientID %>").get_textBoxValue();
           //Setting up the Reg expression for email.
            var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
           var hasInvalidMail = false;

           if (l_EmailText.length < 7) { // valid email to have 7 chars at least
                 return false;
            }

            //split emails if there is ;
            var emails = [];
            if(l_EmailText.indexOf(';') >= 0)
            {
                emails = l_EmailText.split(';');
            }
            else
            {
                emails[0] = l_EmailText;
            }

            //loop all emails
            for(var i=0; i<emails.length;i++)
            {
                if (!reg.test(l_Email)) {
                    //stop checking if we find error
                    hasInvalidMail = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            return hasInvalidMail;            
    }
```

You can make some enhancement to return only the valid emails

Comment: Your code almost working I need to identity if the user put comma or any other char instead of semicolon  between 2 emails or more and replace it with semicolon. Split function doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can also filter out invalid emails and just keep the valid ones. Basically, you push all valid emails to an array in the loop and return it. I would process all emails and then notify the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that most of the code you posted works. I think you just need to check out something like the [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function. As soon as you get `l_EmailText` you could call:

```
var emails = l_EmailText.split(";");
```

to break up each of the emails and then iterate:

```
for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
    // individual email check code goes here
}
```

to check each email individually. Your regex expression `/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;` only appears to work for one email.